# Get max value from each day from a range of time using google sheets arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

[Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f4y2F0fjREmBSBiNgTWLJG_UBLO8WINYVNfR5VznAIg/edit?usp=sharing)

There is range A that stores time and its value and it gets updated dynamically (not in the example).

From that range A, I want to make a dynamic range B of each day and its max value.

Filter() doesn't work with arrayformula and I don't know if query works with it too.

Comment: Can you show the formula you used? I don't see in the Sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it just with a query:

```
=ArrayFormula(query({int(A4:A),B4:B},"select Col1,max(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 label Col1 'Date'"))
```

as long as you format the date column in the result appropriately.

[image]

**EDIT**

To remove the column labels, just put an empty string as below:

```
=ArrayFormula(query({int(A4:A),B4:B},"select Col1,max(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 label Col1 '',max(Col2) ''"))
```

Comment: Is there a way to remove the labels/headers?

Comment: Just put empty string for the labels - plz see edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this (tested on Excel because your Google Sheet is blocked, but it should work perfectly)

`=SUMPRODUCT(MAX(--($A$5:$A$31>D5)*--($A$5:$A$31<D5+1)*$B$5:$B$31))`

[image]

This is how it works:

1. `--($A$5:$A$31>D5)` will return an array of 1 and 0 if cell value is higher than date reference. Say date reference is 24/01/2020, then the returned array will be `{1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1}`
2. `--($A$5:$A$31<D5+1)` will do same, but only if cell value is lower to d5+1 (next day). So for 24/01/2020 we would obtain `{1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0}`
3. First `*` will multiply both arrays, so `{1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1} * {1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0} = {1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0}`
4. Second `*` will multiply previous array by values in range `B5:B31`, that means `{1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0} * {0,333;0,667;0,667;0,667;0,667;0,667;0,667;0,667;0,667;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;0,667} = {0,333;0,667;0,667;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0}`
5. `MAX` will get the **max** value from previous array (in this case, `0,667`)
6. `SUMPRODUCT` has been added so we can work with arrays. Normal Max would not do it by itself.

**NOTE:** Please, notice that my decimal separator is the comma and my argument separator is the semicolon, so probably you will need to fix this acording to your language settings

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=SORTN(SORT(FILTER({INT(A5:A), B5:B}, B5:B<>""), 1, 0, 2, 0), 9^9, 2, 1, 1)
```

[image]