# Get max value from each day from a range of time using google sheets

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, filter, time, array-formulas

I got [this sheet I want to work with](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t5oEfzGOKYQKdWPJRnB4Bp8R52ImBEeN3YLiC69NFSA/edit?usp=sharing) : It's a range of many days, minute by minute. Each minute has a value. I want to obtain a list of each day + the minute of the max value (see example in sheet).

It's very [similar to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63719437/get-max-value-from-each-day-from-a-range-of-time-using-google-sheets-arrayformul). I tried to use and apply the solution to my specific sheet, without any success.

I tried many tings, even to simply made the same thing (so without the minute) than in the post I linked, but can't make it to work.

Any hints, explanations or solution will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORTN(SORT(FILTER({A16:A+B16:B\ C16:C\ INT(A16:A)}; 
 C16:C<>""); 3; 1; 2; 0); 9^9; 2; 3; 1); 9^9; 2)
```

[image]

Comment: That work flawlessly. A great thanks to you player0. It was even more usefull than I thought, as I discover a major flaw in the data recording.

Due to this discover, is there a simple way to add a filter to this formula, to limit the result to time only in a range between 09:00:00 to 20:00:00 ?

Comment: I tried to add a condition to the filter, to filter on B2:B>time(6,0,0) and it bring me an error.

Comment: @user3927850 try: `=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORTN(SORT(FILTER({A16:A+B16:B\ C16:C\ INT(A16:A)}; C16:C<>""; B16:B>=("6:00:00"*1); B16:B<=("20:00:00"*1)); 3; 1; 2; 0); 9^9; 2; 3; 1); 9^9; 2)`